# Loan com. Sent me $$ and asked me to send it back to get a larger loan

Tags: loans, scams

A loan company sent me $$ and then asked that I send it back on a Google Play Card. In order to receive a larger sum loan. Is this a Scam

Comment: Why on Earth would you think that any real business would want money on a Google Play card?  In the (IMHO highly unlikely) event that they were a real business, they'd want actual money, such as a bank transfer.

Comment: You're not sending it BACK. You're sending it to a completely different place.  Or to be more precise, they're the destination, but they weren't the source.   They are tricking you into laundering money for them.

Answer (score 12):

There is exactly one reputable organization in the world which accepts Google Play cards as a payment medium, and that's Google. Anyone else who tries to get you to transfer funds to them that way is doing something illegal.

The money you received was likely obtained from a hacked bank account. The transfer will get reversed as soon as the owner of that account reports the incident to their bank.

But what you won't be able to do is reverse the purchase and transfer of the Google Play card to the scammers.

Update: In a comment to another answer you off-handedly mentioned

> "they knew how much I withdrew without me telling them because they had my bank info".

**That's a very bad no good thing**. When someone unauthorized has access to your bank account, then you should report that to your bank immediately so they can revoke their access. You are likely obligated to do that according to the terms of service of your bank. And if you don't already know how they got access, then you should do your best to find out and prevent anyone else from getting access that way in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely. Exactly how the scam will play out is not certain, but at some point the money that they sent you will get reversed and you'll be responsible for repaying it (and out the gift card money as well).

If I were you, I would first call the bank and let them know what you've done so far so that they can advise you on the next steps.  Do NOT buy a gift card and do not respond to any of the scammers' messages, no matter how threatening they seem. If they threaten violence or legal action then contact the police. Hopefully they will just reverse the payment and leave you alone.

Comment: It sounds like money laundering to me. After I checked my account and saw that they actually sent me $$ to send back to them I was to

Comment: After I checked my account I was shocked that they actually sent me $$ to send back to them.At that point my phone was assaulted with them texting and calling a zillion times this went on for almost an hour. (Swear to God). Now this part was probably stupid of me ,but I did go to the bank and withdrew about 2/3 of it. I didnt do anything with it I still have it, I  gave an excuse that I reached my ATM withdrawal limit and I would withdraw the rest in the morning and send it back to them via Google play card. The whole time I'm thinking you F*****G Scammers....excuse my language. I wanted to

Comment: Buy some time to get more information about this type of scam because come tomorrow morning after 9:00am my phone is going to blow up with calls and texts from them. So my question is, what should I do now? Oh and I left something out they knew how much I withdrew without me telling them because they had my bank info. I feel like a complete idiot.A part of me just wants to take the $$ and run, but the other part is saying bad idea thats not how to handle this..So any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @A.Foco How did they get access to your account balance without your help? Are you telling us the whole story in your question?

Comment: Oh absolutely .... I feel like a complete idiot. My account was in the negative and they sent me $500. The remainder they want me to send back is $350. Which isn't that  much in the sceme of things, but now i feel like I need to change my bank account or even the bank itself for that matter.

Comment: Did they *actually* know how much you withdrew and tell you the amount before you told them, or did you say "I withdrew X" and they said "Yes, we know, we can see your bank account"? In general, every single word they say to you is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, scam. You already figured this out.

Now, here is what you need to do:

First, change your bank password.

Second, put all the money back into your bank account that you withdrew. The bank will eventually be taking this money back and giving it to who it really belongs to, which is not you or the scammer, but another victim.

Third, have a conversation with the bank. Tell them what is going on. You want them to learn about this from you, rather than figuring out about it themselves (which they will do eventually anyway).

Finally, learn your lesson. Don’t trust shady websites. You now know that it was not smart to ignore all the red flags you likely saw as you were dealing with them. Never give your bank password to anyone. There is never a legitimate reason to do this.

Comment: I  did what you advised me to do. I changed my password and contacted my bank.. and just as I predicted they started calling me around 9:30 this morning and kept calling and texting me. I finally had to send them a rude text message and tell them to stop. Whoever else is reading this my advise is don't ignore the signs, I knew this was a Scam, but I was desperate for money and went against my better judgement and fell right into their laps. Now  I guess I have to wait it out and see what repercussions I may or may not suffer. Thanks again for your advice. I'll let you know what happens next.